# battling with serializing xml files writing to database

Tags: c#, sql, xml-serialization

I have tried to serialize xml files into binary in database. I am not sure I wrote code in a right way. I have been goolge around but cannot find answers. I may have missed something. I believe it must be a small problem.

I expect result here:

```
<TestFiles>
 <XmlFile>test001.xml </XmlFile>
 <XmlFile>test002.xml  </XmlFile>
 <XmlFile>test003.xml  </XmlFile>
</TestFiles>
```

i got error result in database:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayO
```

what is possible wrong with my code?

C#:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("XmlFile")]
public class XmlFile
{
    public string FileName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class TestFiles: List<XmlFile>
{
}

    public void SerializeXmlFileToDatabase()
     {
     var files = new TestFiles
                                 {
                                     new XmlFile {FileName = "test001.xml"},
                                     new XmlFile {FileName = "test002.xml"},
                                     new XmlFile {FileName = "test003.xml"},

                                 };

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (TestFiles));
        var ms = new MemoryStream(8096);
        ser.Serialize(ms, XmlFile);



        DbConnection connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = DbFactory.CreateConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
            connection.Open();
            using (DbCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {

                //insert
                var id = Guid.NewGuid();
                command.CommandText = "insert into testtable ([id], [data]) values (@id, @data)";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.AddParameter("id", DbType.Guid, id);
                byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
                command.AddParameter("data", DbType.Binary, data, ParameterDirection.Input, data.Length);
                command.Prepare();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
        }
```

}

Comment: Why are you trying to serialise to binary? XML is string based, not binary based? You could store in an `nvarchar` and be much easier!

Comment: Try using ToArray() instead of GetBuffer() on a memory stream.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here. You say you're trying to serialize to binary, but you've used an XML Serializer.

If you want to store XML in the database, just store it as XML.

If, for some reason, you do need to store XML as Binary, you'd want to use a Binary Serializer, and pass your object containing your XML to it.

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter BF = new BinaryFormatter();
        BF.Serialize(stream, objectToSerialize);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        // Do stuff with your stream

    }
```

But really ask yourself - why am I trying to store XML as binary?